# "Aim for hard problems" vs "Aim for solving hard problems"

Tags: phrases

In my resume, I want to communicate I enjoy solving hard problems. I used a phrase

> backend programmer with an aim for hard problems

In my natural language leaving out the `solving` word does not make any difference.

However, I wonder does it make any difference in English? In other words, is the meaning of the phrase above any different the following one?

> backend programmer with an aim for solving hard problems

Comment: The use of *solving* changes the meaning conveyed, although it's a little subtle. However, I would replace *aim* with something like *desire*, *flair*, or *aptitude*. The use of *aim* in this context is a little strange.